# How do I only pass one parameter to a function when it expects two?

Tags: parameters, kotlin

```
fun multipleParams(id: Int = 1 , name: String) {
  ...
}
```

I created the above method in the class. The following method call is a working correctly with:

```
multipleParams(1,"Rose")
```

Is it possible to use it in a way, such that sometimes I pass only `name` and sometimes both?

```
multipleParams(1,"Rose")
multipleParams("Rose")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there -- you just need to *utilize* [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments) since you've already have them named:

```
multipleParams(name = "Rose")
```

This will use the default value of `1` for `id` as it is not passed and use `"Rose"` for `name`. You can't simply use positional arguments here because you're not supplying the first argument, so use the names you've given.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add on to the answer of @Andrew Li.

You can just change the order of arguments to achieve that.

```
fun multipleParams(name: String, id: Int = 1) {
  ...
}
```

Now you can call function following way:

```
multipleParams("Rose", 1)
multipleParams("Rose")
```

Note: Preferably default arguments should be at the end of function parameters. Then you need not use named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add on to the @chandil03's answer.

**"default arguments should be at the end of function parameters"** ,but except the [Function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) parameter, if you want to using [Lambda Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions), for example:

```
fun multipleParams(name: String, id: Int = 1, block: () -> Unit) {
    ...
}

multipleParams("Rose") {};
multipleParams("Rose", 1) {};
```